# wp all import custom function to replace an attribute within in image URL

Tags: php, wordpress

I’m using WP All Import to import products. I’ve run into a bit of an issue with trying to map product variation images.

My XML file contains an `<ItemNo>`

Each variation has the same product name and variations are handled by different item numbers in this manner

```
<ItemNo>450042-02</ItemNo>
<ItemNo>450042-05</ItemNo>
<ItemNo>450042-07</ItemNo>
```

These are the image url is

```
/ImageServices/image.ashx?itemid=450042&config=02&format=l&imagenumber=1
```

if you break this down

- `450042&config=02` would match to 450042-02
- `450042&config=05` would match to 450042-05

and so on

- `&format=l`, `&format=s` (this represents large or small image
  and i think image number is irrelevant at this point)

if I put below in the image url

```
/ImageServices/image.ashx?itemid={ItemNo[1]}&format=l&imagenumber=1
```

it would output the following which won’t work

> https://domain.com/ImageServices/image.ashx?itemid=450042-02&format=l&imagenumber=1

so i’d need to change the hyphen to `&config=`

wp all import accepts custom functions, anyone know a function to replace the `-` to `&config=` in the `{ItemNo[1]}` in only the image section?

Comment: I don't know if I understand, but simply `str_replace( '-', '&config=', $itemString )` ?

Comment: Thanks! This worked [str_replace("-", "&config=",  {ItemNo[1]})]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to achieve something like the following:

```
 $string = '450042-02';

 echo "\n";
 // part before the -, itemid
 print_r(substr($string, 0, strpos($string, "-")));
 echo "\n";
 //part after the -, config
 print_r(substr($string, strpos($string, "-") + 1));
 echo "\n";
```

Although I have never used WP All Import
But Referencing here http://www.wpallimport.com/documentation/advanced/execute-php/

It seems that you can run php function within `[]` square brackets.

So you field mappings should become like

`/ImageServices/image.ashx?itemid=[substr({ItemNo[1]}, 0, strpos({ItemNo[1]}, "-"))]&config=[substr({ItemNo[1]},strpos({ItemNo[1]}, "-") + 1)]&format=l&imagenumber=1`

What I am not sure about, would it be able to handle the + operators etc or not but you can try.

If it doesn't work then you can create custom functions like `get_my_itemid($string)`, `get_my_config($string)`, using code(the substr logic) above and then use it in your Img. URL instead of `substr`

Comment: Hey thanks for the tips. This seemed to do the trick [str_replace("-", "&config=",  {ItemNo[1]})]. Looks like I didn't need a custom function after all.